# Efficient (faster) computation of sparse matrix product using Eigen c++ library

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen, matrix-multiplication

Following Zienkiewicz's Finite Element Method text, I am solving a linear elasticity problem with linked subdomains. In short, I need to compute the following triple sparse matrix product:

```
Q * V^-1 * Q^T
```

where `Q` is an n-by-m sparse matrix and `V` is an m-by-m symmetric positive-definite sparse matrix. Typically, n >> m. Currently, the following code produces correct results but is slow relative to my expectations:

```
using namespace Eigen;
typedef double Scalar_t;
typedef SparseMatrix<Scalar_t,ColMajor> Sparse_t;

int n, m;
Sparse_t result(n,n);
Sparse_t V(m,m);
Sparse_t Q(n,m);

//begin
SimplicialLDLT<Sparse_t> solver(V);
assert(solver.info() == Success);

//this is required because all my sparse matrices are column-major
Sparse_t QT(Q.transpose());
result = QT.transpose() * solver.solve(QT);
```

Given the sparsity, symmetry, and overall ideal character of `Q` and `V`, I would expect there to be a better way of doing this. One idea I have is to use the LLT decomposition instead.

```
V = L * L^T
V^-1 = L^-T * L^-1
Q * V^-1 * Q^T = (Q * L^-T) * (L^-1 * Q^T)
```

Because `(Q * L^-T)^T = L^-1 * Q^T` I should be able to use a symmetric rank update for the final matrix product. This works, but is even slower than the above method!

```
SimplicialLLT<Sparse_t> V_solver(V);
assert(V_solver.info() == Success);
Sparse_t L(V_solver.matrixL());
SparseLU<Sparse_t> L_solver(L);
assert(L_solver.info() == Success);
Sparse_t QT(Q.transpose());
Sparse_t L_inv_QT = L_solver.solve(QT);
result.selfadjointView<Lower>().rankUpdate(L_inv_QT.transpose());
```

From a linear algebra perspective, the LLT method should involve less work and leverages all the nice properties of my matrices. I wanted to use the triangularview solver, i.e.: `V_solver.matrixL().solve(QT)` but that only accepts dense rhs arguments. The solveinplace version of the triangular view solver doesn't work either, probably because my rhs argument is rectangular (would involve changing the dimensions of the matrix).

Any ideas? This is the bottleneck of my application. Thank you!

EDIT:

Per Avi Ginsberg's post [Understanding solveInPlace operation in Eigen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59519048/understanding-solveinplace-operation-in-eigen/59519960#59519960)

I was not using solveInPlace correctly. This allows me to directly compute `L^-1 * Q^T` with a triangular solver and perform the symmetric rank update. The following code results in 67% less run time. That is what I was expecting!

```
SimplicialLLT<Sparse_t> solver(V);
assert(solver.info() == Success);
Sparse_t tmp(Q.transpose());
solver.matrixL().solveInPlace(tmp);
result.selfadjointView<Lower>().rankUpdate(tmp.transpose());
```

Avi, feel free to copy this snippet and I'll mark your post as the answer.

Comment: What compiler/flags/hardware are you using? Also, what times do you expect/get? Can you post a benchmark?

Comment: I am using all the default eigen compiler flags and am using Visual Studio 2017, with the default Release mode compiler settings and optimizations. No openmp.

I did a rudimentary benchmark by averaging several runs with various methods

1) LDLT decomposition on V: 10.04 sec; 
2) LLT decomposition on V : 12.20 sec; 
3) LLT decomposition on V, LU decomposition on resulting L, and symmetric rank update: 11.71 sec. 

As for my expectations, I thought using a symmetric rank update method would be far more efficient. I am just curious if I am going about this the best way possible.

Comment: @AviGinsburg You answered my question in a previous post! 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59519048/understanding-solveinplace-operation-in-eigen/59519960#59519960

I in fact did NOT understand solveinplace. I am now getting an average of 3.9s. Not sure how to attribute the answer to you, as I am mostly a SO reader.

Comment: you can either write up an answer yourself, or flag this question as a duplicate of the other. If you don’t feel it’s a duplicate, write up an answer.

Comment: Also, if performance is a priority, I would switch compilers if that’s an option. MSVC doesn’t play very well with Eigen.

Comment: Are you sure that you need the actual product `Q * V^-1 * Q^T` or just the product of that with another vector/matrix? Typically, `V^-1` will be dense (even if `V` was sparse), making the whole product dense. And with `m >> n` it will even be a highly rank deficient dense matrix, which is about the least effective way of storing that.

Comment: @chtz you are correct that V^-1 is not sparse, but Q * V^-1 * Q^T is surprisingly sparse (0.7% sparsity). The real issue is that the above expression is a condensation of a larger block matrix problem of the form {{K Q},{Q^T, -V}} {u,l} = {f,0}. This is equivalent to (K + Q * V^-1 * Q^T) * u = f. Solving the condensed system has demonstrated to be much faster than the block form. I tried using the Woodbury Matrix identity to directly solve the above system without taking any inverses, but it was a huge mess. There probably is a way of doing it, but it was beyond me.

Comment: If `K` is much larger than `V` it is spurious to me why you don't do the block-matrix solving the other way around (i.e., compute `V + Q^T K^-1 Q`) -- assuming of course `K` is also easy to invert. For dense `V^-1`, the matrix `Q * V^-1 * Q^T` should only be sparse, if `Q` has a lot of zero-rows (or if there is a lot of cancellation).

Comment: @chtz Q is very sparse -- it serves to constrain the motion of finite elements on a particular surface of my mesh. 

If I understand you correctly, you are using the Woodbury identity: `(K + Q * V^-1 * Q^T)^-1 = K^-1 - K^-1 * Q * (V + Q^T K^-1 Q)^-1 * Q^T * K^-1`. K is relatively easy to invert (symmetric positive definite). I hadn't tried it because it involved inverting two matrices instead of one.

Comment: It is just [blockwise inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Blockwise_inversion) starting with the top-left block instead of the bottom right block. Note that for solving an equation you only need to fully form (and decompose) the `V+Q^T*K^-1*Q` block. The question which way is better usually mostly depends on whether `K` or `V` is larger (but may depend on the structure of `V` and `K` of course). Note that in your case you also need to decompose `K + Q * V^-1 * Q^T` when solving for `u`